# Extend menu class to mainActivity class

Tags: android, menu, android-activity

I have a menu class that I want to be able to access from my mainactivity class. this is a snip of the menu class. I am unsure how to make the menu accessable.

```
public class lifeMenu extends Activity {
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.life_menu);
  }
```

Comment: This is not a menu class, this is another Activity. How do you want to use it in your main activity?

Comment: I want the menu to pop up when the menu button is clicked. I have the whole menu code in the lifeMenu class but what I want is for the main activity to be able to call the class without having to put the menu code inside the mainactivity class.

Comment: override onCreateOptionsMenu() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to popup menu, u need to use onCreateOptionsMenu method overrided.. u dont need of using it as another activity..